# Scrapy spider with IMAGES_STORE on DigitalOcean Spaces

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, scrapy, digital-ocean

I need help with the IMAGES_STORE setting for my scrapy spider.

I am hosting with DigitalOcean and would like to download the images to their Spaces.

My scrapy app is intergrated with a django website. I am already using Spaces to store the images for the django website using the instructions here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-object-storage-with-django

It is very similar to the settings for AWS S3.

The API endpoint for my space is https://ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com

According to the [scrapy documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html?highlight=image_store#amazon-s3-storage) the AWS settings are as follows...

```
IMAGES_STORE = 's3://bucket/images' 
IMAGES_STORE_S3_ACL = 'public-read'
```

I've tried adapting this for DigitalOcean Spaces but have been unsuccessful.

I've already tried

```
IMAGES_STORE = 'https://ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com/media'
```

and

```
IMAGES_STORE = 's3://ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com/media'
```

Any help on this would be great.

Comment: Please, do let us know if Tomáš Linhart’s answer works.

Comment: @Lennybee were you able make scrapy store scraped images on Digitalocean spaces ? Facing the same problem.

Edit: in case someone comes across this, a possible solution is described here: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/4998

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to DigitalOcean Spaces nor Amazon S3 so take this just as a starting point. Looking into [API documentation](https://developers.digitalocean.com/documentation/spaces/) for DigitalOcean Spaces (where is an example for Python) and [Scrapy code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/pipelines/files.py) for the `FilesPipeline` (which `ImagesPipeline` is based on), I would say you also need to adjust at least `AWS_ENDPOINT_URL` in `settings.py`, maybe also other `AWS_*` options.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have already included settings for: 
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY 
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME 
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL

It did not work with these in place